# Crawl space water

Tags: repair, water, concrete, walls, basement

We have had 3 straight days of rain and I noticed a small amount of water seeping under scrawl space wall. My space has a vapor barrier and is in decent shape. I did notice the finder blocks on frame of space are dark/damp on each side. Assume it is water making its way down through ground. Any suggestions to help? I will tackle ways to drain better around the foundation and away from my house. Is this normal for water in crawl space?

Comment: Is surface water collecting on the side of the foundation where the water is coming in or is this water coming up from a raised water table?

Comment: It is wet and soggy along where I think it is but not puddles. Probably from raised water table under ground. I am in Georgia so lots of clay opposed to soil. Also my home is on a hill and everything flows one way. The crawl space and where it’s wet is on the high end of the house. It is most flat in terms of the ground where I feel water is collecting.

Comment: What has worked out well for me was to pipe every last drop of water from my gutters on the high side of my house, which happens to be the front, to the back yard.  In ridged pvc drain pipe. Even with the non stop rain we've had my basement is dry, which hasn't always been the case. Proper grading along the house and gutter management has gone a long way for me.

Answer (score 2):

When there is uphill ground leading down to a house the standard intervention is to locate an underground drain (a so called "French drain") to intercept the ground water and surface water and conduct it around the foundation and downhill away from the foundation.

In some cases the trench for this drain (3 ft or 4 ft deep and filled with gravel or crushed rock over a perforated pipe) is located close to the house (within 3 ft) and in others it is placed farther away.

Comment: I know many homes have water in there crawl space after a real but with your scenario Jim's answer would prevent water from collecting.+